# Anonymous endpoint unreachable to guest users

Tags: .net, authentication, authorization

I'm working on ASP.NET API project and curiously enough, during debugging process, I found out that I can't access an endpoint marked as anonymous in an authorized controller. It ends execution and throws an exception, as if user need to provide its credentials. It doesn't when endpoint is anonymous, right? This is the piece of the code where an exception is thrown (`ForbiddenUseCaseExecutionException`):

```
public TResponse HandleQuery<TRequest, TResponse>(
        IQuery<TRequest, TResponse> query,
        TRequest data
    )
{
    try
    {
        var isAuthorized = _user.UseCaseIds.Contains(query.Id);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            throw new ForbiddenUseCaseExecutionException(query.Name,_user.Username);
        }
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var result = query.Execute(data);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(query.Name + " Duration: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms." + isAuthorized);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

And relevant controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class ServiceSchedulesController : ControllerBase
{
    private UseCaseHandler _handler;

    public ServiceSchedulesController(UseCaseHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    // GET: api/<ServiceSchedulesController>
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Get(
        [FromQuery] ServiceSchedulesSearch search,
        [FromServices] IGetServiceSchedulesQuery query
        )
    {
        return Ok(_handler.HandleQuery(query, search));
    }
}
```

It should have allowed request to go through, I suppose, skipping authentication and authorization altogether.